# Pythonic way to read csv files from a folder in repository

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

In one of our repositories we have a folder called `player_test` where we store all `player_test` related `.py` files. We realized that there are certain static `csv` files we use to do some processing. So we decided to create a folder called `player_test_input` inside the player_test folder. The `player_test_input` should store all the `csv` files.

**CODE**

```
def get_player_call_logic_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "../dev/player-assignment/src/player_test/player_test_input/player_call_logic.csv"
    )
    return df
```

**Issue**

In the above function `get_player_call_logic_df` I read the `csv` using relative path.

However I am not sure if there is a more pythonic way to do this?

We use pathlib quite a bit in our codebase and avoid using relative path but was not sure how that would apply in this case. I am always trying to figure out how i can use the modern python features and best practices more.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the directory other than its position relative to the current one? For instance, is it assumed to be in the home directory, or some other well-known path?

Comment: Yes it is assumed to be in a well known path. The way we use our code base is we use aws where we launch ec2 instances and our source code is in a known directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that: 1) the path should be a function argument 2) but the function as it stands is very short and does only one thing - you actually don't need a function for this because there is nothing particular that can be reused.

Since the file is going to reside in a specific path, use a constant, it can be defined inside a config file. Quite likely, you may have other options or hardcoded stuff, so it's good to use a config file to keep it all in the same place.

eg:
config.py

```
PLAYER_FILES_DIR = "/dev/player-assignment/src/player_test/player_test_input/"
```

And then in your code you import the config file and you can refer to the location path as config.PLAYER_FILES_DIR:

```
import config

df = pd.read_csv(config.PLAYER_FILES_DIR...)
# do something
```

pathlib can still possibly be used if you intend to read multiple files from the directory.

Comment: The problem is i can not use absolute path because while the absoloute path will work for times when this code is run on a ec2 instance but when folks run it locally it won't work so i would have to use a relative path. So would it be fine if i stored relative path as a constant?